# Magento 2 infinite scroll issue

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, html

I am using a magento 2 custom infinite scroll module. When I scroll down ajax request initiate and response come with new page content . But this response not updating on current content . I checked the selector which is fine. 
I can see below warning . Is this related to above issue?

```
$(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using **Layered Navigation** extension also along with **Infinite Scroll / Ajax Scroll**?

There are many extension providers who suggests that both extensions didn't work together.

How many of you agree?